# regular expression pattern [#[#hello]#] match in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

```
var str1 = "hello <span contenteditable="false" class="underlineText hashtags hello">hello<span style="display:none;"> [#[#hello]#] [#[#hi]#]  [#[#welcome]#]</span></span>"

var arr = textToPost.match(/#^[a-zA-Z0-9]/g)
```

I want to extract string which matches this pattern [#[# * ]#] .

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression , it works with me

```
var reg = /\[[#[a-zA-Z0-9]+]#]/ig;
```

```js
var str1 = "hello hello [#[#hello]#] [#[#hi]#] [#[#welcome]#]";
var reg = /\[[#[a-zA-Z0-9]+]#]/ig;
var arr = str1.match(reg);
console.log(arr)
```